# Transformation under rotation for electrons and photons

Tags: quantum-spin

For the question [What all has intrinsic spin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203774/what-all-has-intrinsic-spin/203792#203792) it was answered that

> Spin is a number that tells you how the state of the object transforms under rotations.

How I imagine such rotations for photons and for electrons?

Comment: Imagine rotating the laboratory apparatus rather than the system (in this case, a particle) being observed. This is a “passive rotation” rather than an “active rotation”. They are equivalent.

Comment: @G.Smith To 90° or 180° and in which direction(s)?

Comment: If the system has a particular spin, it will transform in a particular way under a rotation by any angle on any direction. The details are called the representation theory of the rotation group. The simplest rotation to consider is a 360-degree complete rotation around any axis. For systems with half-integral spin, this is not the same as no rotation!

Comment: @G.Smith ... and only for special angles (180°, 360°) the state will be the same as the previous state. I guess the direction of rotation does not matter.

Comment: The direction doesn’t matter if you can treat space as isotopic. But if there are external fields affecting the system, though, you can’t do that.

Comment: @G.Smith For half spin I rotate 180° and for spin 1 it is 360°?

Comment: To get back to the original state before rotation?

Comment: Yes, to go back

Comment: For spin 1/2 you have to rotate 720 degrees to get back. For spin 2 you only have to rotate 180 degrees.